# Passing and retrieving multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I can best explain my problem by showing the code first. I am working on a project with my friend (Rent a car project), so the code isn't completely mine. I searched (and used) some of the answers i found on similar questions, but none solved my problem. All of the pages here will be used by administrator.

1st
    client_requests.php

This page contains javascript function called sureToApprove with which i have a problem : in the url the car variable is undefined (&car=undefined), while id has a value (it works). Also, this page contains some of the data from database.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function sureToApprove(id, car) {
        if (confirm("Da li ste sigurni?")) {
            window.location.href = "approve.php?id=" + id + "&car=" + car;
        }
    }
    function deleteRequest(id){
        if (confirm("Da li ste sigurni?")) {
            window.location.href = 'delete_request.php?id=' + id;
        }
    }
    </script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        load_data();
        function load_data(query) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "fetch_requests.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: { query: query },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        $('#search_text').keyup(function () {
            var search = $(this).val();
            if (search != '') {
                load_data(search);
            }
            else {
                load_data();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

2nd page is `fetch_requests.php` which contains a query which will be shown on 1st page (client_requests.php). Query and the rest of the code works perfectly.

```
   <tr>
                    <td>'.$row["fname"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["lname"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["phone"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["car_name"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["mpesa"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>
                    <td>
                       <a href="javascript:deleteRequest('.$row['client_id'].')" class="ico del">Izbriši</a>

<a href="javascript:sureToApprove('.$row['client_id'].', '.$row['car_id'].')"class="ico edit">Approve</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

When the link approve is clicked, it redirects to 3rd page (approve.php) in which the data in database is regulated. The url looks something like this

```
http://localhost/Rent-a-car/admin/approve.php?id=7&car=undefined
```

I need the car variable for regulating the database, and i can't find out why it is not picking up the value instead is undefined. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is car defined? Perhaps you should for testing purposes build in a check for it having a value and console log errors if it is not the case.

Comment: I assigned $row['car_id'] value to a test variable outside of function, and it shows correct value. However, when i pass it as an argument `sureToApprove('.$row['client_id'].', '.$row['car_id'].`, to this function function `sureToApprove(id, car) {
        if (confirm("Da li ste sigurni?")) {
            window.location.href = "approve.php?id=" + id + "&car=" + car;
        }
    }` , car in the url has undefined value.